# Precision recall curve when results of estimator known

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the results of an estimator running on `X`, as well as the ground truth, and I want to use `plot_precision_recall_curve`, but that requires passing in the `estimator` and `X` - which I can't do, the estimator is very complex and resides in another system... What should I do? (it would be nice to have a version of `plot_precision_recall_curve` that takes in `y_pred` and `y_true` ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [precision_recall_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve) which accepts `y_true` and `y_pred`, and returns `precision`, `recall`, and `thresholds`, to be used further to find [f1_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) and [auc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html), the latter can let you plot it manually.

This is an [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-classification-in-python/):

```
# precision-recall curve and f1
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from matplotlib import pyplot
# generate 2 class dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2, random_state=1)
# split into train/test sets
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=2)
# fit a model
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
model.fit(trainX, trainy)
# predict probabilities
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX)
# keep probabilities for the positive outcome only
lr_probs = lr_probs[:, 1]
# predict class values
yhat = model.predict(testX)
lr_precision, lr_recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(testy, lr_probs)
lr_f1, lr_auc = f1_score(testy, yhat), auc(lr_recall, lr_precision)
# summarize scores
print('Logistic: f1=%.3f auc=%.3f' % (lr_f1, lr_auc))
# plot the precision-recall curves
no_skill = len(testy[testy==1]) / len(testy)
pyplot.plot([0, 1], [no_skill, no_skill], linestyle='--', label='No Skill')
pyplot.plot(lr_recall, lr_precision, marker='.', label='Logistic')
# axis labels
pyplot.xlabel('Recall')
pyplot.ylabel('Precision')
# show the legend
pyplot.legend()
# show the plot
pyplot.show()
```

[image]